# Is there a way to "flatten" enums for (de)serialization in Rust?

Tags: enums, rust, serde

I have an enum that is composed of other enums, similar to the following (`serde` derives and annotations omitted for brevity):

```rust
enum Main {
    A(SubA),
    B(SubB),
}

enum SubA { X1, X2, X3 }
enum SubB { Y1, Y2, Y3 }
```

I'd love to be able to use `serde` to deserialize a string such as "X1" or "Y3", and automatically get back a `Main::A(SubA::X1)` or `Main::B(SubB::Y3)`, respectively.

I understand that `serde` supports a `#[serde(transparent)]` attribute on newtype-style structs, which would do what I like. However, it only seems to work on the struct or enum level, not at the enum-variant level. Is there a way I can automagically get the behavior I'm looking for? I can ensure that there would be no overlap in any of the variant names in any of the contained sub-enums.

Aside from wanting to remain on Rust 2018 stable, I have no other restrictions on my project, and I'm open to any crate suggestions that would help.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this out of the box. You can try manually implementing Deserialize and Serialize as in examples https://serde.rs/custom-serialization.html

Comment: @Stargateur There are already examples in the question for what the OP wants. Specifically, if input is the string `X1`, output should be `Main::A (SubA::X1)` and if input is `Y3`, output should be `Main::B (SubB::Y3)`…

Comment: I am not sure if `serde` implements this out of the box, because it seems hard to do when you have an enum holding the same type in different variants (i.e. `enum Main{A(SubA), B(SubA)}`. What should `X1` then be deserialized to? (Similar problem if `SubA` and `SubB` both contain a variant `X1`.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It works pretty much out of the box if you put `serde(untagged)` on the outer enum and nothing special on the inner enums:

```rust
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Main {
    A(SubA),
    B(SubB),
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
enum SubA { X1, X2, X3 }

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq)]
enum SubB { Y1, Y2, Y3 }

fn main() {
    let x1 = Main::A(SubA::X1);
    let y2 = Main::B(SubB::Y2);

    assert_eq!(serde_json::to_string(&x1).unwrap(), "\"X1\"");
    assert_eq!(serde_json::to_string(&y2).unwrap(), "\"Y2\"");

    assert_eq!(serde_json::de::from_str::<Main>("\"X1\"").unwrap(), x1);
    assert_eq!(serde_json::de::from_str::<Main>("\"Y2\"").unwrap(), y2);
}
```