# Serialize/Deserialize CSV with nested enum/struct with serde in Rust

Tags: csv, rust, enums, serde

I want to serialize/deserialize a CSV file with variable row length and content, like the following:

**./test.csv**

```
Message,20200202T102030,Some message content
Measurement,20200202T102031,10,30,40,2
AnotherMeasurement,20200202T102034,0,2
```

In my opinion, the easiest way to represent this is the following `enum`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum Record {
    Message { timestamp: String, content: String }, // timestamp is String because of simplicity
    Measurement { timestamp: String, a: u32, b: u32, c: u32, d: u32 },
    AnotherMeasurement { timestamp: String, a: u32, b: u32 },
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]¬
csv = "^1.1.6"¬
serde = { version = "^1", features = ["derive"] }
```

Running the following

**main.rs**

```rust
fn example() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .delimiter(b',')
        .flexible(true)
        .double_quote(false)
        .from_path("./test.csv")
        .unwrap();
    for result in rdr.deserialize() {
        let record: Record = result?;
        println!("{:?}", record);
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn write_msg() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let msg = Record::Message {
        timestamp: String::from("time"),
        content: String::from("content"),
    };
    let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
        .has_headers(false)
        .flexible(true)
        .double_quote(false)
        .from_writer(std::io::stdout());
    wtr.serialize(msg)?;
    wtr.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = example() {
        println!("error running example: {}", err);
    }
    if let Err(err) = write_msg() {
        println!("error running example: {}", err);
    }
}
```

prints

```sh
error running example: CSV deserialize error: record 0 (line: 1, byte: 0): invalid type: unit variant, expected struct variant
error running example: CSV write error: serializing enum struct variants is not supported
```

**Is there an easy solution to do this with `serde` and `csv`?** I feel like I missed one or two `serde` attributes, but I was not able to find the right one in the documentation yet.

***EDITS***

[Netwave suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69418163/11761856) adding the `#[serde(tag = "type")]` attribute. Serializing now works, Deserializing gives the following error:

```
error running example: CSV deserialize error: record 0 (line: 1, byte: 0): invalid type: string "Message", expected internally tagged enum Record
```

---

**Research I did that did not lead to a solution yet**

[Is there a way to "flatten" enums for (de)serialization in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532247/is-there-a-way-to-flatten-enums-for-deserialization-in-rust)

https://docs.rs/csv/1.1.6/csv/tutorial/index.html

[Custom serde serialization for enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66088020/custom-serde-serialization-for-enum-type)

https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html

Answer (score 1):

Make your [enum tagged](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#enum-representations) (internally tagged specifically):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type")]
pub enum Record {
    Message { timestamp: String, content: String }, // timestamp is String because of simplicity
    Measurement { timestamp: String, a: u32, b: u32, c: u32, d: u32 },
    AnotherMeasurement { timestamp: String, a: u32, b: u32 },
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03b72840eb492266beffe660f3ac1895)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solves serializing, giving the output `Message,time,content`. Deserializing however gives the following output:
`error running example: CSV deserialize error: record 0 (line: 1, byte: 0): invalid type: string "Message", expected internally tagged enum Record`
I update the question with your answer.

Comment: @LewinProbst, did you use the headers? Most probably you need headers otherwise it will not know what to relate the first field to.

Comment: Actually it doesnt work with the headers. I bet csv doesnt support that and by using the tagged one we tricked it into serializing, but it is not smart enough to desarialize.

Comment: Hm yes seems like this is not possible, and it will not be added:
https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv/issues/211

Comment: @LewinProbst, maybe its time to write a fully serde compatible csv crate ;)